# Unable to return BlockHashes when I run this generatetoaddress

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup, command-line-options

I have downloaded and fully synced with my Mac last Saturday, my Bitcoin Core version is v0.21.0 and my Bitcoin-Qt version 5.9.8.

I did run other RPC commands such as "getrpcinfo" and it did provide result:

{
"active_commands": [
{
"method": "getrpcinfo",
"duration": 72
}
],
"logpath": "/Users/jsjs77/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/debug.log"
}

"getbalance" -
￼
{
"mine": {
"trusted": 0.00000000,
"untrusted_pending": 0.00000000,
"immature": 0.00000000
}
}

But then, when I want to run this "generatetoaddress nblocks "address" it does not provide block hash result:
￼
generatetoaddress 11  1MDihWw2UfkYyAwrQDWNFbmaH6bx4NBFtL

￼
[

]

I have tried the following methods:

bitcoin-cli generatetoaddress 11  1MDihWw2UfkYyAwrQDWNFbmaH6bx4NBFtL.

￼
Method not found (code -32601)

and

bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 11 1MDihWw2UfkYyAwrQDWNFbmaH6bx4NBFtL

￼Method not found (code -32601)

Is this got to do with the changes of latest version? I really need help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `bitcoin.conf` and its default location on Mac is *$HOME/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf*
2. Save `bitcoin.conf` with:

```
regtest=1
```

3. Launch Bitcoin Core. You should see a logo color similar to stackexchange:

[image: regtest-qt]

4. Open console and run the below commands:

A. `getnewaddress`

B. `generatetoaddress` `11` [*Address returned in A*]

[image: console-regtest]

Comment: You can create a new file with name `bitcoin.conf` and save `regtest=1` in it.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response but when I "right-click" there is no option for me to choose to create a new file.

Comment: Open [terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location) and run `touch bitcoin.conf`

Comment: yes and I did.. In the bitcoin.conf - I have insert the following command in terminal:  echo "regtest=1" >> ~/.bitcoin.conf.     But when I open back, sorry to inform that my Bitcoin Core is not same as yours. Sorry, did I miss anything?

Comment: do you have other suggestions, if you think that I have follow accordingly above but it does not reflect on the Bitcoin Core regtest=1? I need to overcome this problem, thanks.

Comment: You can also try running `bitcoin-qt --regtest` in terminal. It works in Linux: https://i.imgur.com/la4Bj3a.png I am not sure about Mac.

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thanks.